# Optimum way of writing this ruby code in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is a good way of writing something like this in one line. The goal is to log the message at info level if the value is nil else in debug mode, along with proper message like the one shown. Seems simple, but writing 5 lines of code for something small like this keeps bothering me. I can wrap this in method, but would like to avoid if I can.  Thanks.

```
if value.nil?
  Rails.logger.info "value: nil"
else
  Rails.logger.debug "value: #{value.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: how many times are you writing this in your code? if the answer is N >= 2, create a method `log_values(value)` for it, problem solved!

Comment: The preferred style in ruby is to create a method.  Don't avoid it, embrace it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
value.nil? ? (Rails.logger.info "value: nil") : (Rails.logger.debug "value: #{value.inspect}")
```

Another way you can try (this is not the same, but similar):

```
Rails.logger.send (value.nil? ? :info : :debug), "value: #{value.inspect}"
```

But the best way I think is to write you own logger, that automatically decides which variable in which flow is written:

```
NullLogger.log value
```

Comment: That's ok, but that kind of code might be accompanied by a note along the lines "it can be done, but are you sure you want to write this mess"? though that particular snippet is not a total mess, granted.

Answer (score 0):

```
value.nil? ? Rails.logger.info "value: nil" : Rails.logger.debug "value: #{value.inspect}"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `value.nil? == true`?
Also, boolean comparison is rather prolix, though not really a problem.

Comment: Yes. it's a comparison here. agree

Answer (score 0):

```
value ? Rails.logger.debug("value: #{value.inspect}") : Rails.logger.info("value: nil")
```

Comment: If `value` is `false`, it will take the `nil` condition. It is better to use `value.nil?` if the user wants to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in one line, just remove the line breaks:

```
if value.nil? then Rails.logger.info "value: nil" else Rails.logger.debug "value: #{value.inspect}" end
```

But why, oh why, would anyone want to do this?